# How to find out the the definition of gradle executed task in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gradle, gradlew

I am new to SCM tool like Jenkins so I may not actually ask the right question.

I find out there is a specific Gradle executed task failed when check the logs of Jenkins.
However, I cannot find out where the Gradle executed task is defined and what is the content of it.

I look up the `[CONFIGURE]` of Jenkins and then in the `[BUILD]` section, there is a section called `[Invoked Gradle script]` and I could see the name (lets call it `X` here) of executed Gradle task I am looking for.

But I cannot find where `X` is really defined and what command it actually run, Does anyone has any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using gradle in verbose mode

```
gradle -S build
-S, --full-stacktrace
   Print out the full (very verbose) stacktrace for any exceptions. See also logging options.
```

or try using debug mode

```
-d, --debug
    Log in debug mode (includes normal stacktrace).
```

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html

Answer (score 0):

> Gradle provides a Domain Specific Language (DSL), for describing builds. This uses the Groovy language to make it easier to describe a build. Each build script of Gradle is encoded using UTF-8, saved offline and named as build.gradle.

By default, Gradle command will invoke Gradle script from `build.gradle` file.

> You can run a Gradle build using the Gradle command. This command looks for a file called build.gradle.

More details [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/gradle/gradle_build_script.htm).